# Android get GPS coordinates

Tags: android, permissions, gps

I'm trying to get the latitude and longitude of an android device using the following code:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

I also set my permissions in the manifest file as following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

However, the permission is not getting granted for some reason and I can't run the code that creates the location. I'm not sure what else I need to do to get the permissions verified. Any suggestions?

Comment: FYI-  even when you solve that problem you're going to have null pointer exceptions-  getLastLocation can return null.

Comment: The code hits the `return;` statement?

Comment: Yes, it hits the return statement every time

Comment: Never mind, I made a noob mistake. I didn't turn on location services for the app on my phone.